# Hide sibling div on hover with css only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-class

I am interested in a way of making CSS(no javascript) show off a `div` or an element outside of the one you `:hover`, like so:

```css
#divid {
  display: none;
}
a:hover #divid {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover me!</a>
<div id="divid">Hello there, fellow friend!</div>
```

I am pretty curious, because I want to make a thing while you hover a certain menu element, you will get the search bar drawn to the left edge of the browser(it'll be `position: fixed;`).

---

**EDIT:**

The above code  was not actually whatI wanted, I think.

This is the actual code, since it doesn't work anyways by the answers.

```css
#fixed2 a:hover + .nav {
  background: black;
}
#options:hover + #search_text {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li id="left" class="big">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="35px" src="square.png" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="left" class="arrow">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="arrow.png" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="left">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="17px" style="margin-left: -7px" src="refresh.png" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li id="left">
    <a href="#">
      <img width="18px" style="opacity: 0.94; margin-top: -1px;" src="help.png" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <div id="fixed">
    <li id="search">
      <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search" />
        <input type="button" name="search_button" id="search_button">
      </form>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div id="fixed2">
    <li class="icn" id="options">
      <a href="#">
        <img width="25px" src="settings.png" />
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Why doesn't it work properly and just actually work?

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**  you can't achieve what you want in CSS with your current markup, because CSS doesn't have a parent CSS selector, check [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), So two options:

- Do this via JS
- Change your current markup in the way the element which is going to hover and be hovered are siblings (like your previous example and my answer below)

---

you can use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `+`

```css
#divid {
  display: none;
}
a:hover + #divid {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover me!</a>
<div id="divid">Hello there, fellow friend!</div>
```

if you have an extra siblings between them you can use the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `~` which is less strict

```css
#divid {
  display: none;
}
a:hover ~ #divid {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover me!</a>
<div id="sibling">I'm sibling too</div>
<div id="divid">Hello there, fellow friend!</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:**
When using the plus sign between css selectors you are actually saying that:

1. When you hover above `<a>`
2. Target closest/sibling `div`.
3. Using your setup you can move the target element around only when using javascript.
4. It can **not** be done.

**Showing when things break:**

I added `<p>` tag between `#divid` and `<a>` on purpose. Now I am trying to target closest element to `#divid` that should be `<a>` but it isn't. So my css breaks.

```css
#divid {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
a:hover + #divid {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover me!</a>
<p>
P tag is in the way.
</p>
<div id="divid">Hello there, fellow friend!</div>
```

**Snippet moving element around:**

You need to respect css selectors. Try to break your code down to smaller pieces and then slowly add more and more complexity.

```css
#divid {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
}
a:hover + #divid {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover me!</a>
<div id="divid">Hello there, fellow friend!</div>
```

**Snippet:**

```css
#divid {
  display: none;
}
a:hover + #divid {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Hover me!</a>
<div id="divid">Hello there, fellow friend!</div>
```

Comment: It is just an example. I will edit the code. It can by any element you want as long as it has a proper class/id.

Comment: Alright, can i ask you for the actual code, 'cause i really don't get it.

Comment: Sure give me a second. :)

Comment: look my post. maybe you know what to do :))

Comment: I just edited my answer. Try to break your code down to smaller pieces. Add complexit slowly. For example: #fixed2 a:hover + .nav will not work. Because "a" is not a sibling of #fixed2. You are trying to target element that does not exist.

Comment: I cannot comment directly to your answers because I am currently trying to build my "reputation".

Comment: You can not achieve your goal without using jQuery. I can help you with jQuery though. It is really easy.

Comment: well i don't think i will even use css but i am a curious person and i was intruded about why doesn't this work.. and yes i will use javascript or jQuery because i cannot tell if a user scrolls down the page and make the menu smaller and modify it, but not right now, i am pretty sleepy(EU PST)

Comment: Why should it mark it if this is not answering to the question?

Comment: Well I told you it is not possible using your setup and explained why.